# R: applying function to matrix except individual cell(s)

Tags: r, indexing

Suppose I have a 10x10 matrix. How can I fill it with 0's while excluding certain individual cells (preferably in a single operation)?

```
blank <- matrix(NA,nrow=10,ncol=10)
for (i in 1:10) {for (j in 1:10) {blank[i,j] <- 0 }}
# except blank[2,5], blank[9,3], blank[1,4], to be left NA
```

Comment: In order to fill you marix with zeros just do `blank[] <- 0`. Regarding the `NA`s, is there some rule here or there are just random cells? If there no algorithm behind it, you"ll probably need to do each one individually.

Comment: Thanks for the simpler method. Yes, they are intended to be random.

Answer (score 2):

Probably more efficient to rather declare the matrix as 0s and assign the `NA`s to the small number of exception cells:

```
blank <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
blank[2, 5] <- blank[9, 3] <- blank[1, 4] <- NA
```

Or, more programmably:

```
coords <- list(c(2, 5),
               c(9, 3),
               c(1, 4))

blank[do.call("rbind", coords)] <- NA
```

(the key being this part of `?"["`):

> When indexing arrays by `[` a single argument `i` can be a matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of `x`; the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of `i`.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `blank[cbind(c(2,9,1), c(5,3,4))] <- NA`

Comment: @docendodiscimus that's better (more programmable), I'll add it in. Thanks, my indexing skills are lacking.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, coords)` will be probably more efficient for a big list.

Comment: @DavidArenburg good call. Never realized `Reduce` has a huge `for` loop built in.

Comment: Boy, that list/do.call/rbind operation surely appears clunkier than what  `docendo discimus` suggested.

Comment: @42-, the point of the latter option is that it's the easiest to extend to a less specific situation. If the coordinates are not known but given by some object (here, a `list`, to extend the generality introduced by docendo--e.g., it's easy to imagine getting a `list` of coordinates from having done `lapply`), this gives one approach for handling that. I also think it's easier to digest with `rbind` than with `cbind` since the coordinates are always given side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

If this is supposed to be a random assignment of NA to a zero matrix then this might suffice.

```
 zero3NA <- matrix(0, 10, 10)
 zero3NA[ cbind( sample(nrow(zero3NA), 3), sample(ncol(zero3NA), 3) ) ] <- NA
```